# how can I solve axios headers problem in typeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

I have changed my CRA react APP into TypeScript and I have a problem below.
I think `sessionStorage.getItem('accesstoken')` should be `undefined` or `string` or `null`
and I don't know how to type this object.

```js
 axios
        .post(
          `${process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL}/pick`,
          {
            festivalId: newPick.festivalId,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              accesstoken: sessionStorage.getItem('accesstoken'),
            },
          }
        )
```

[image]

Comment: You will have to check it the .getItem returns null. You can either pull it out into a variable and check, or use the nullish coalescing operator to give a default `accesstoken: sessionStorage.getItem('accesstoken') ?? '',` or whatever value you want to give if there's nothing stored.

Comment: Thanks!! Actually I don't know well about nullish coalescing operator but, as soon as I put `?? ''` in my code, it works!!

Answer (score 1):

It's because null is not accepted as request header value, so you can check if it's exist send if not set undefiend,so it won't send accessToken if it's null

like this :

```
 headers: {
              accesstoken: sessionStorage.getItem('accesstoken') ?? undefiend,
            },
```